# Logs of Azure Durable Function in Application Insights

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-durable-functions

I see the following logs in Application Insights after running an Azure Durable Function:

[image]

Does 'Response time' indicate the execution time of each function? If so, is there a way to run a kusto query to return the `Response time` and `name` of each function?

Comment: Yes, see [some examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/samples?pivots=azuremonitor#aggregations) of how to use grouping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Response Time is the time taken to complete execution
or
Response Time = Latency + Processing time.

You can use the below kql query to pull the function name and response time

```
  requests  
 | project timestamp,functionName=name,FuncexecutionTime=parse_json(customDimensions).FunctionExecutionTimeMs,operation_Id,functionappName=cloud_RoleName
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Is the response time indicated in milliseconds?

Comment: Yes, as mentioned in the above screenshot the response time is mentioned in milliseconds.